# Failed to sync Gradle project Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:design:27.1.0]

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

> ERROR: Error:Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:design:27.1.0] on DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.android.support.test.espresso', name='espresso-core', version='2.2.2', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager. Open Android SDK Manager

build.gradle (Module app)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.salmakhalil.signupformwithdatabase"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
       // androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
       implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
// implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
//implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
//        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
//        implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//        implementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
//        implementation 'com.android.support.test.expresso:expresso-core:3.0.1'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

How should I solve this problem?

```
**build.gradle** (Module App)
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.salmakhalil.signupformwithdatabase"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
/*    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
       // androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
       implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
// implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
//implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
//        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
//        implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//        implementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
//        implementation 'com.android.support.test.expresso:expresso-core:3.0.1'
    })*/
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

---

````
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.


buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        // { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        //maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

/*configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0'
}*/```
````

Comment: replace implementation with compile

Comment: you should say replace compile with implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all update the version of android plugin for gradle and the gradle version.

In the project `build.gradle` (top-level file) update the android plugin changing:

```
repositories {
        google() //<-- add
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2' //change
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() //<-- add
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
}
```

Then in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` change the gradle version using `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip`.

To fix the issue in the question, in the `module/build.gradle` change:

```
   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
       // androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
       implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    })
```

to:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
```

Comment: @Marcin thank you for your reply. I pasted your replacement but still facing same error.

Comment: @salmakhalil which version of android plugin are you using? Post the build.gradle in root folder.

Comment: @salmakhalil The error may be different after changing , just check once again

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I have edited the question and added the build.gradle. Now you can check the  android plugin

Comment: @salmakhalil Sorry but it is the module/build.gradle file. Post please the build.gradle that you can find in the root of the project (not of module)

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti UPADTED. Please check

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti NOW its showing Error:(23, 0) Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.

Comment: @salmakhalil Sorry my bad. In `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` change the gradle version using `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, thanks and updated. Now its showing Error:Support for clients using a tooling API version older than 3.0 was removed in Gradle 5.0. You are currently using tooling API version 2.14.1. You should upgrade your tooling API client to version 3.0 or later.

Comment: @salmakhalil  this is a separate problem. Maybe you have to update Android Studio. In any case it has nothing to do with your question. You may wish to consider asking a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
   // androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
})
```

To

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
```

Comment: replaced your one. but now its ahowing  ```Error:(35, 0) Could not find method androidTestImplementation() for arguments [androidx.test:runner:1.2.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
openFile:C:\Users\Salma Khalil\AndroidStudioProjects\signupformwithdatabase\app\build.gradle">Open File```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code from this:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

To this:

```kotlin
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
```

Then Add in gradle properties:

`android.useAndroidX=true`